# ASP.NET Identity's way of hashing password Compared to Crypto.HashPassword

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, asp.net-identity

Good Day everyone. I'm currently creating a Login Form in Xamarin.Forms Portable application. I have a WebFormsProject, wherein I created an API controller that compares the username and password typed by the User versus the username and password saved on my Database.

The password saved on my database is Hashed using ASP.NET Identity. While the password that will be typed by the User is hashed using **Crypto.HashPassword** (don't know if this class is an ASP.NET Identity thing).

How can I compare this two?

If the two password matched, it should return 'true' otherwise false. I'm on a confusing stage right now. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Here are some of my codes.

**LoginController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using WebFormsDemo;
using WebFormsDemo.ViewModel;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;


namespace WebFormsDemo.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        private EBMSEntities db = new EBMSEntities();

        // GET: api/Login


        [Route("api/Login/Search/{username}/{password}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(List<AspNetUser>))]


        public bool getUsernamePassword(string username, string password)

        {



            var hashedPassword = "";
            hashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(password);


            var pass = (from u in db.AspNetUsers
                        where u.UserName.Equals(username)
                        select u.PasswordHash).Take(1);

            string hashpassinDb = Convert.ToString(pass.FirstOrDefault());

            return Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hashpassinDb, hashedPassword);




        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Password hashes are usually compared using the method VerifyHashedPassword from the PasswordHasher class. check this link: [Verifies that a password matches the hashed password.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordhasher.verifyhashedpassword(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(System.String,System.String))

**Edit:**
As per comment *It turns out that using Crypto.HashedPassword will produce a Hash Value different from the Hash value saved on my database.*

You need to provide `IPasswordHasher` implementation that can provide clear password without hashing.

```
public class ClearPassword : IPasswordHasher
{
    public string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        return password;
    }
}
```

Will give you clear password which you can use to compare with entered password.

Comment: what should I do with this? It's just a declaration? What hashing algorithm is used in ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista, *what should I do with this?* You can use this and solve your issue, *It's just a declaration?* Yes it is. *What hashing algorithm is used in ASP.NET Identity* Is the same as this :https://brockallen.com/2012/10/19/password-management-made-easy-in-asp-net-with-the-crypto-api/)

Comment: I applied it to my code. It turns out that using Crypto.HashedPassword will produce a Hash Value different from the Hash value saved on my database. Simply because they have different hashing algorithm.

Comment: Do I really need to create a separate class for this ClearPassword? Is it possible to just include this in the current LoginController.cs I have? If yes, how should my code look like?

Comment: As per my suggestion you've to add a separate class.  *Is it possible to just include this in the current LoginController.cs*  you can try with add class in a controller but it's not best practices.

Comment: If I have created the ClearPassword class, how can I use this in my LoginController?

Comment: Classname.methodname, and pass your password text

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to return Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword isn't meant to be hashed, it's meant to be plain text.